# can't get globe to rotate in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to get a d3 globe to rotate to a particular country when you click that country in a list. To start out, I'm trying to get the following example working (I got it from http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5994804), but it throws an error TypeError: world is undefined from line 100. Can anyone help, please?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Earth globe</title>
<script src="./d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./d3/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./d3/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.water {
  fill: #00248F;
}

.land {
  fill: #A98B6F;
  stroke: #FFF;
  stroke-width: 0.7px;
}

.land:hover {
  fill:#33CC33;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.focused {
  fill: #33CC33;
}

select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 580px;
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd8dc;
}

.countryTooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

</style>
<body>
  <script>

  var width = 600,
  height = 500,
  sens = 0.25,
  focused;

  //Setting projection

  var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
  .scale(245)
  .rotate([0, 0])
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
  .clipAngle(90);

  var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

  //SVG container

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

  //Adding water

  svg.append("path")
  .datum({type: "Sphere"})
  .attr("class", "water")
  .attr("d", path);

  var countryTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "countryTooltip"),
  countryList = d3.select("body").append("select").attr("name", "countries");


  queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/raw/5685937/world-110m.json")
  .defer(d3.tsv, "http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/raw/5685937/world-110m-country-names.tsv")
  .await(ready);

  //Main function

  function ready(error, world, countryData) {

    var countryById = {},
    countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

    //Adding countries to select

    countryData.forEach(function(d) {
      countryById[d.id] = d.name;
      option = countryList.append("option");
      option.text(d.name);
      option.property("value", d.id);
    });

    //Drawing countries on the globe

    var world = svg.selectAll("path.land")
    .data(countries)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "land")
    .attr("d", path)

    //Drag event

    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function() { var r = projection.rotate(); return {x: r[0] / sens, y: -r[1] / sens}; })
      .on("drag", function() {
        var rotate = projection.rotate();
        projection.rotate([d3.event.x * sens, -d3.event.y * sens, rotate[2]]);
        svg.selectAll("path.land").attr("d", path);
        svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);
      }))

    //Mouse events

    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      countryTooltip.text(countryById[d.id])
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 7) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px")
      .style("display", "block")
      .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      countryTooltip.style("opacity", 0)
      .style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      countryTooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 7) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px");
    });

    //Country focus on option select

    d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
      var rotate = projection.rotate(),
      focusedCountry = country(countries, this),
      p = d3.geo.centroid(focusedCountry);

      svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);

    //Globe rotating

    (function transition() {
      d3.transition()
      .duration(2500)
      .tween("rotate", function() {
        var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);
        return function(t) {
          projection.rotate(r(t));
          svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path)
          .classed("focused", function(d, i) { return d.id == focusedCountry.id ? focused = d : false; });
        };
      })
      })();
    });

    function country(cnt, sel) { 
      for(var i = 0, l = cnt.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(cnt[i].id == sel.value) {return cnt[i];}
      }
    };

  };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're running this locally, you need to run a webserver as described [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).

Comment: I have Windows 7 and am running it locally from http://localhost. Not using Python.

Comment: See comment above. You need to run a webserver.

Comment: ? It seems I do have a local web server - I've been developing on it for years, with and without mysql. The page you provided does not state anything further I need to do to configure an MS IIS web server locally.

Comment: Ok, if you have a webserver than it's something else. Did you check the `error` variable?

Comment: The files aren't local, so that's not the problem.  You're probably getting cross-origin errors.  [Google for more](https://www.google.ca/search?q=xmlhttprequest%2Bcross-origin%2Berror)

Comment: It seems that the json and tsv files couldn't be read. I moved them locally and solved the problem. Thnx, all!